# Change invalid textbox value - VB NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, isnumeric

I currently have 3 textboxes. Each textbox must contain a number. If any one of the three textboxes does not contain a numeric value, show an error message. For textboxes not displaying a number, (where IsNumeric returns false), I want to change its default value. How do I do this?

```
If Not (IsNumeric(txtpadult.Text)) Or Not (IsNumeric(txtpjunior.Text)) Or Not (IsNumeric(txtpconc.Text)) Then
    MsgBox("ERROR: INVALID NUMERIC !", vbCritical, "System Message")
End if
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Chozo...I've read your question a few times, and I'm still just  not exactly sure what you're needing...could you clarify?

Comment: If either txtpadult or txtpjunior or txtpconc is false, make the false statement to text properties with property value.

Comment: Chozo, I took the liberty of editing your question to make your objective a bit clearer.

Comment: your code is just determining if ANY textbox is bad and not determining WHICH tb is bad. see Steven Doggart's answer

Answer (score 4):

First, I would recommend using the new .NET methods, when possible, rather than resorting to the old VB6 style methods.  So, instead of `MsgBox`, I would recommend using `MessageBox.Show`, and instead of `IsNumeric`, I would use `Integer.TryParse`, etc.

So, for instance, you could rework your code like this:

```
Dim invalid As TextBox = Nothing
If Not Integer.TryParse(txtpadult.Text, 0) Then
    invalid = txtpadult
ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(txtpjunior.Text, 0) Then
    invalid = txtpjunior
ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(txtpconc.Text, 0) Then
    invalid = txtpconc
End If
If invalid IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: INVALID NUMERIC !", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    invalid.Text = "0"  ' Set to default value
End If
```

As you can see, as it tests each text box, if it finds one that is invalid, it keeps a reference to it in the `invalid` variable.  Then it can check to see if one was found and set it's value.  Alternatively, you could create a list of text boxes which need to be checked and then loop through them, like this:

```
Dim textBoxes() As TextBox = {txtpadult, txtpadult, txtpconc}
Dim invalid As TextBox = Nothing
For Each i As TextBox In textBoxes
    If Not Integer.TryParse(i.Text, 0) Then
        invalid = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If invalid IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: INVALID NUMERIC !", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    invalid.Text = "0"  ' Set to default value
End If
```

Or, if you want to be clever, you can do it in less lines of code with a LINQ extension method:

```
Dim textBoxes() As TextBox = {txtpadult, txtpadult, txtpconc}
Dim invalid As TextBox = textBoxes.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) Not Integer.TryParse(x.Text, 0))
If invalid IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: INVALID NUMERIC !", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    invalid.Text = "0"  ' Set to default value
End If
```